# xml layout loads but my activity doesn't respond to button clicks

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, actionlistener, android-fragmentactivity

I'm new at this but I already made a small app that worked the same way.
I can't see what I'm doing wrong because the code looks quiet the same as my previous app.

When I run it or debug my app it shows my layout on my emulator so it does load the page that has to be loaded but that's all it does, it doesn't listen to button clicks. I also gives me no errors.

Here's my XML code for fragment_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

 <TextView
        android:text="Eventaris"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="100px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/lblEventaris"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/login">


     <EditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Gebruikersnaam"
         android:id="@+id/txtGebruikersnaam"/>

     <EditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Wachtwoord"
         android:inputType="textPassword"
         android:layout_below="@id/txtGebruikersnaam"
         android:id="@+id/txtWachtwoord"/>

     <Button
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Inloggen"
         android:id="@+id/btnInloggen"
         android:layout_below="@id/txtWachtwoord"/>

    </LinearLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_below="@id/login">

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="nog geen account?"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/lblRegistratie"/>

      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Registeren"
          android:id="@+id/btnRegistreren"
          android:layout_below="@id/lblRegistratie"/>
         </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my fragmennt activity MainFragment.Java

```
    package com.example.arno.eventaris;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Arno on 28/04/2015.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnMainFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private View view;

    public MainFragment()
    {
        //required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button btnInloggen = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnInloggen);
        btnInloggen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    inloggen();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        Button btnRegistreren = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistreren);
        btnRegistreren.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                navigeerRegistratie();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            mListener = (OnMainFragmentInteractionListener) activity;

        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    public void inloggen() throws SQLException {
        EditText gebr=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtGebruikersnaam);
        EditText wachtw=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtWachtwoord);
        String gebruiker = gebr.getText().toString();
        String wachtwoord = wachtw.getText().toString();

        mListener.login(gebruiker, wachtwoord);
    }

    public void navigeerRegistratie()
    {
        mListener.navigeerRegistratie();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnMainFragmentInteractionListener {
        //Todo: Update argument type and name
        public void login(String gebruiker, String wachtwoord) throws SQLException;
        public void navigeerRegistratie();
    }



}
```

Here is my Main Activity MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.arno.eventaris;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.arno.eventaris.Database.DBAdapter;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MainFragment.OnMainFragmentInteractionListener,RegistratieFragment.OnRegistratieFragmentInteractionListener{

    private Cursor gebruikerCursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void login(String gebruiker, String wachtwoord) throws SQLException {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        db.open();

        gebruikerCursor = db.getGebruiker(gebruiker);
        if(gebruikerCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            gebruikerCursor.moveToFirst();
            String wwControle = gebruikerCursor.getString(gebruikerCursor.getColumnIndex("wachtwoord"));

            if (wachtwoord.equals(wwControle)) {

                HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("gebruikersnaam", gebruiker);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            } else {
                DialogFragment errorlogin = new ErrorLogin();
                errorlogin.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wachtwoord incorrect!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DialogFragment errorlogin = new ErrorLogin();
            errorlogin.show(getFragmentManager(), "Gebruikersnaam incorrect!");
        }
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void navigeerRegistratie() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new RegistratieFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void registreren(String gebruiker, String voornaam, String naam, String email, String wachtwoord, String herhaalWachtwoord) {
        if(wachtwoord.equals(herhaalWachtwoord)) {
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

            db.open();
            long id = db.insertGebruiker(gebruiker, voornaam, naam, email, wachtwoord);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();
        }
        else
        {
            DialogFragment errorregistratie = new ErrorRegistratie();
            errorregistratie.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

And as last here is my activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both Login and Registration buttons aren't responding?

Comment: Indeed, when I click them absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint inside my onCreateView method and then debugged it. Seems like it's not getting called. It still loads my layout though.

Comment: Can you see the buttons on your screen? If so then your _onCreateView_ is getting called.

Comment: I see everything perfectly yes but it doesn't take a break at my breakpoint.

Comment: I tried using a log statement in inloggen() and can't seem to find a log file so I don't think it's getting called but it also could be that I'm not using my log parameter right, I followed a tutorial on how to do it because it's my first time.

Comment: Use Log.d() and change the filter to "debug" in your IDE's Log where everything gets printed.

Comment: I used Log.d("Testing", "Checkpoint 1"); insede inloggen() and it seems like it's not printing anything in my logcat when I click the button so I guess it doesn't get called.

Comment: Still nothing happening

Comment: Don't change it, there's nothing wrong with that line. But put a Log just before and after your first if statement in your _login()_ method inside the MainActivity and see if both Logs are getting printed or just one.

Comment: But I already put a Log in Inloggen() in MainFragment.java which leads to MainActivity login() so if it doesn't get called there it also won't get to MainActivity.

Comment: I believe Inloggen() is getting called.

Comment: But my logcat doesn't show my log inside that method.

Comment: Where did you call this method _public void registreren(String gebruiker, String voornaam, String naam, String email, String wachtwoord, String herhaalWachtwoord)_

Comment: Part of another fragment that I already made, when you click the registreren button you should switch to the fragment where it's called

Comment: It doesn't intefere with this fragment normally

Comment: Is it possible that it is my genymotion that's doing something wrong? Because I can't find a thing wrong with my code..

Comment: No, I've used Genymotion too. It has nothing to do with this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Or maybe a missing link between my fragment and acitivity?

Comment: I fixed it by making a new project, thanks for your help anyway prudhvi, realy appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by making a new project with the same code, had to be a problem way deeper than my code.